# yadcf>filter_type: “text”>filters_position: 'footer' fails to search

Tags: yadcf

I'm having issue when search text box are in the footer position. The search box is not functional when setting filters_position: 'footer' to yadcf. When setting is removed the text search box do there thing. Anything else I need to do? Thanks in advance and Awesome plug-in.

https://jsfiddle.net/4hqm9tsh/2/

Setting scrollX: to false I'm now able to search with in the column. I'm hoping to keep this true.

```
                      {
                            column_number: 6,
                            filter_default_label: "", 
                            filter_type: "text",
                            style_class: 'yadcf-sb',
                            filter_delay: 1000,
                            filter_reset_button_text: false 
                        },              
            ],
                        { filters_position: 'footer' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in yadcf which I just fixed and released in new `0.9.3.beta.8`,

see it in [action here](https://jsfiddle.net/4hqm9tsh/6/)

If you will encounter this in other filter type please open a bug in yadcf repository.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that specifying scrollY in the DataTables settings is causing the footer not to filter anything. Needs fixing.

Comment: you can open an issue then in yadcf repo (must provide a test page)